# jquery live with "bstip" tooltip?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, live

I'm using bstip to have some nice tooltip on my images.

I load my images with an ajax call to get:

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="bslink" title="exemple" />
<img src="2.jpg" class="bslink" title="exemple" />
```

but when using

```
$('.bslink').bstip();
```

it's not working.

How can I use 'live' with jQuery in this case?

Comment: Can't you just call `bstip` when you receive the AJAX response?

Comment: Are including the css files in your page?

Comment: You don't need `.live()` to accomplish this. Simply place `$('.bslink').bstip();` in your AJAX call's success method.

Comment: @Mrchief : Yes css is including. Works fine without an ajax call

Comment: Then sounds like @Georges tip should do the trick. Otherwise, can you post your ajax code?

Answer (score 0):

Output

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="bslink" title="exemple" />
<img src="2.jpg" class="bslink" title="exemple" />

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.bslink').bstip();
});
</script>
```

from ajax response and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .live() to accomplish this. Simply place $('.bslink').bstip(); in your AJAX call's success method.